# Receive multiple files from pipe and write to different destinations

Tags: bash, pipe, tar

I have this command locally:

```
  nc localhost 3440 | tar -x -O > ores.tgz
```

if I receive one file from the server, it will be written to ores.tgz in my pwd.

However, if I receive multiple files from the server, it looks like only the last file I receive will be saved to the file, probably overwriting all of the previous ones.

So my question is - is there some way to save multiple files to different filenames in my pwd, using a similar command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save it with timestamp suffix in this manner:

```
nc localhost 3440 | tar -x -O > ores-$(date +%s.%N).tgz
```

It will produce files with names like this:

```
ores-1526341128.393345176.tar.gz
ores-1526341129.366798510.tar.gz
ores-1526341332.305878646.tar.gz
ores-1526341332.545975256.tar.gz
ores-1526341332.786026292.tar.gz
```

Of cause you can remove nanosecond precision (`%N`) if your intensity of download isn't high.

Comment: wow I never would have thought that would be the way to do it!

Comment: I wonder how why this works under the hood